# Error: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 451 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error

Tags: java, email, outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have tried to execute below the code.

```java
public class Sendmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "abc@outlook.com";
        String from = "xyz@outlook.com";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("TEXT!");
            message.setText("The message is here");
            System.out.println("Sending");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully");
        } catch (MessageException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the above program I got queue file write error in Transport.send(message) line. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Are there any issues with my code or is this a server problem?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Is that really the mail host?  That particular error message *looks* like a Postfix error.

Comment: Yes the mail host is same. I'm getting this error @StephenC

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your mail properties are wrong.

Try setting the "mail.transport.protocol" property to "smtp".   Your current props assume that the protocol is *defaulting* to "smtp".  If it doesn't then the "mail.smtp.host" and "mail.smtp.port" properties will be ignored, and default host and port will be used instead.

My suspicion is that in your case the host is defaulting to "localhost" ... and that the machine you are running the Java application on is not configured to *receive* email.  (There are hints that the host has Postfix installation, but that could be wrong.)

Comment: I have tried this but still it is throwing the same error @Stephen C

Comment: Try using a packet monitoring tool or something to see whether your application is actually establishing a connection to "smtp.office365.com".  Also check that you are using the server as recommended in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365.  It may be that there really is a problem on the Office365 mail server(s) ... but it is more likely that you are doing something wrong.   For example, are you running on a host with a static IP address as required?

Comment: Oh yea ... and check that your organization (or ISP) permits outgoing connections to port 25.  It is possible that they are being *diverted* by a firewall.  (A lot of organizations and ISPs are very sensitive about rogue applications on their network doing unauthorized spamming, etc.)